# Laravel vue-multiselect error

Tags: laravel-5, vue-component

I am trying to implement vue-multiselect (version 1.1.3) with Laravel 5.

In my vue file I have this code:

```
    <template>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <multiselect
                :seleted="multiValue"
                :show-labels="false"
                :options="options"
                :placeholder="placeholder"
                :searchable="true"
                :allow-empty="false"
                :multiple="true"
                key="name"
                label="name"
                @update="updateSelected"
        ></multiselect>
        <label v-show="showLabel" for="multiselect"><span></span>Language</label>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { Multiselect } from 'vue-multiselect';

    export default {
        components: { Multiselect },
        props: {
                selected: null,
                options: {
                    type: Array, default: function () {
                        return []
                    }
                },
                placeholder: 'Select...'
        },
        methods: {
            updateSelected (newSelected) {
                this.selected = newSelected
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In my blade file:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <drop-down
                        :options="{{ $members_list->toJson() }}"
                ></drop-down>
            </div>
```

In my controller:

```
 $members = DB::table('members')
            ->orderBy('member_first_name', 'asc')
            ->get();

        $members_list = $members->map(
            function($member) {
                return [
                    "value" => $member->member_id,
                    "label" => $member->member_first_name. " ". $member->member_last_name
                ];
            }
        );
```

When I run the page I get a select list with all the members in it, but when I try to select one, it turns Red,  it is added to the selected list on top but I cannot select more options and in firebug I get this error:
[Vue warn]: You are setting a non-existent path "selected" on a vm instance. Consider pre-initializing the property with the "data" option for more reliable reactivity and better performance.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Typo might be causing issues?

```
:seleted="multiValue"
```

Should be :selected="multiValue"

BTW :selected is deprecated in the version 2.0. :value has taken it's place.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because there is no variable called 'multiValue' in your component.
In **:seleted="multiValue"** , using the variable "**options**" instead of "**multiValue**"